# Is there a place to report API data errors for the HERE browse search API?

Tags: here-api

When using `requests.get('https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse?apiKey=' + YOUR_API_KEY + '&at=53.544348,-113.500571&circle:46.827727",-114.000519,r=3000&limit=10&categories=800-8200-0174')` I get a response that shows Canadian postal codes - but only the first 3 characters.

For example, I get this data:
`{'title': 'Boyle Street Education Centre', 'id': 'here:pds:place:124c3x29-d6c9cbd3d53a4758b8c953132db92244', 'resultType': 'place', 'address': {'label': 'Boyle Street Education Centre, 10312 105 St NW, Edmonton, AB T5J, Canada', 'countryCode': 'CAN', 'countryName': 'Canada', 'stateCode': 'AB', 'state': 'Alberta', 'county': 'Alberta', 'city': 'Edmonton', 'district': 'Downtown', 'street': '105 St NW', 'postalCode': 'T5J', 'houseNumber': '10312'}, 'position': {'lat': 53.54498, 'lng': -113.5016}, 'access': [{'lat': 53.54498, 'lng': -113.50105}], 'distance': 98, 'categories': [{'id': '800-8200-0174', 'name': 'School', 'primary': True}, {'id': '800-8200-0295', 'name': 'Training & Development'}], 'references': [{'supplier': {'id': 'core'}, 'id': '36335982'}, {'supplier': {'id': 'yelp'}, 'id': 'r3BvVKqluzrZeae9FE4tAw'}], 'contacts': [{'phone': [{'value': '+17804281420'}], 'fax': [{'value': '(780) 429-1458', 'categories': [{'id': '800-8200-0174'}]}], 'www': [{'value': 'http://www.bsec.ab.ca', 'categories': [{'id': '800-8200-0174'}]}]}], 'openingHours': [{'categories': [{'id': '800-8200-0174'}], 'text': ['Mon-Sat: 09:00 - 17:00', 'Sun: 10:00 - 16:00'], 'isOpen': False, 'structured': [{'start': 'T090000', 'duration': 'PT08H00M', 'recurrence': 'FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA'}, {'start': 'T100000', 'duration': 'PT06H00M', 'recurrence': 'FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:SU'}]}]}`

Notice that the postal code listed is "T5J". This is incorrect. Canadian postal codes are 3 characters, a space, and then 3 more characters. I'm guessing this is a parsing error that occurred when the data was captured. The correct postal code is "T5J 1E6".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, HERE has a tool to modify the poi address information.
I reported this poi postal code to be updated to "T5J 1E6".
Please visit below the web tool.
https://mapcreator.here.com/place:124c3x29-d6c9cbd3d53a4758b8c953132db92244/?l=53.5450,-113.5016,18,normal

Thank you!